# Python: create new columns from rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I've been poking around a bit and can't see to find a close solution to this one:

I'm trying to transform a dataframe from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

Such that `remark_code_names` with similar `denial_amounts` are provided new columns based on their corresponding `har_id` and `reason_code_name`.

I've tried a few things, including a groupby function, which gets me halfway there.

```
denials.groupby(['har_id','reason_code_name','denial_amount']).count().reset_index()
```

But this obviously leaves out the `reason_code_names` that I need.

[image]

Here's a minimum:

```
pd.DataFrame({'har_id':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],'reason_code_name':[16,16,16,16,16,16,16,22,22],
             'remark_code_name':['MA04','N130','N341','N362','N517','N657','N95','MA04','N341'],
             'denial_amount':[5402,8507,5402,8507,8507,8507,8507,5402,5402]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby()` is a good way to go. Use it along with `transform()` and overwrite the column with name 'remark_code_name. This solution puts all remark_code_names together in the same column.

```py
denials['remark_code_name'] = denials.groupby(['har_id','reason_code_name','denial_amount'])['remark_code_name'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))

denials.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

If you really need to create each code in their own columns, you could apply another function and use `.split()`. However you will first need to set the number of columns depending on the max number of codes you find in a single row.

Comment: Thanks! Sura-da. I also added this to create those extra columns, and then concatenate back to the original dataframe. denials_final = pd.concat([denials,denials['remark_code_name'].str.split(';',expand=True)],axis=1)

This assumes this prior tweak: ...transform(lambda x : ';'.join(x))